# What does the "tenacious" badge reward?

Tags: support, badges, zero-score-badges

I've been wondering about the tenacious badge for some time, now I've been informed I got it. I understand the condition of winning the badge, but what is its purpose? What does it reward?

Comment: There is also the Unsung Hero badge.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

> Tenacious - Zero score accepted answers: more than 5 and 20% of total.

It's kind of a consolation badge.  It's recognition that you post useful, working, accepted answers even though at least 5 of these answers went without the upvotes they may have deserved.

An answer accepted with a score of 0 sounds to me like a working answer that didn't get the upvotes it was due.  That is what this badge rewards.

Answer (score 23):

Everything John says is correct, but in addition:

- It rewards activity in low(er) traffic tags, where there tends to be a lower number of active users to upvote.
- It also rewards those who are willing to help new(er) users with less than 15 reputation who do not yet have the right to upvote.

Comment: Thanks. Great explanation. Of all the badges I've come across so far, the Tenacious one is the one where the "purpose" is the least clear.