# Please, add more detailed description of badges, explaining why should I respect the user bearing them

Tags: feature-request, badges, badge-description

There is a lot of questions about the same problem: **"What does Tenacious badge mean?"**

The short description of the badge is really hard to understand *(as shown in the [question 69322](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/69322/better-description-of-tenacious-badge))*, and a lot of questions received an answer with pointer to the [List of all badges with full descriptions](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/67397/what-is-each-badge), and this link often was enough to enlighten the asker.

**Jeff Atwood** [answered](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/97081/153157) the question "[Why is the description on the badges page so sparse?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/97071/153157)" with suggestion that more descriptive descriptions would be too confusing for the users, and the badges should be surprise, not a goal.

**I humbly insinuate** that while that answer seems to match the [original question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/34432/153157) it has been quoted from, for *that* question it is not a good answer. A small link would not clutter the page readability. Also if there are badges, and they are displayed publicly, then their description should be understandable. Hiding a good description of some component smells a little like security-by-obscurity.

There is a lot of questions concerning this topic, and a lot of them has no accepted answer. *(I upvoted these questions, but I doubt it will draw attention to them, as they are usually pretty old.)* For example:

- "[Please improve the description of the Organizer badge](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/55574/153157)" - asked a year ago, no answer,
- "[Make badges more descriptive](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/75751/153157)" - the accepted answer is a link to the list,

Two answers for the question **"[What does the “tenacious” badge reward?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/110111/153157)"** form a beautiful description of the badge - they answer the question "Why this badge exists", and "What good has been done by this user".

I understand that Jeff does not want to see the descriptions which tell us **"what should I click to get this badge"**, but the descriptions like these two mentioned above are a different thing. Similar descriptions tell me **why should I respect the user bearing this badge**.

Maybe not all badges need more details - probably bronze ones do not. So, how about adding a short description in this style?

Comment: *If you want me to wear 37 pieces of flair, like your pretty boy over there, Brian, why don't you just make the minimum 37 pieces of flair?*